# getting empty page after adding ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

[image]

I am new to angularjs ,i add a custom directive in my app and also ui-router and now i am getting empty pages nothing is displayed.how can i resolve this issue i am really get stuck in this issue.anyone guide me?
i just setup my app on plunker you can see all code there.

Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/D5S2c6rgycWFfsyfhN9J?p=info

i got following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: scotchApp is not defined
homeDirective.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: scotchapp is not defined
code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:9503 
 Error: [ng:areq] Argument     
'mainController' is not a function, got undefined
```

my index.html :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

        <!-- define angular app -->
         <html ng-app="scotchApp">

         <head>
          <!-- SCROLLS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

        <!-- SPELLS -->
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
          <script src="homeDirective.js"></script>
       </head>

          <!-- define angular controller -->
        <body ng-controller="mainController">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
           <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
         </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
         <div ui-view></div>

         </div>

         <footer class="text-center">
               View the tutorial on <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating">Scotch.io</a>
         </footer>

         </body>

       </html>
```

Comment: check your developer console

Comment: @Ronnie Uncaught ReferenceError: scotchApp is not defined
homeDirective.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: scotchapp is not defined
code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:9503 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined it gives these error i don'nt know why?

Comment: note that error shows 2 spellings of `scotchApp`. Check for typos

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate little

Comment: Look at error you posted ... `scotchApp` vs `scotchapp`

Comment: @charlietfl you can look at code on plunker app is defined but still give error that app is undefined

Comment: did you see updated answer below and fix that?

Comment: @charlietfl yup i fix that but still nothing is displayed

Comment: plunker is a mess...your paths are wrong for templates...scotchApp is undefined. Keep checking console for errors and look at network tab to see failed template loading

Comment: @charlietfl i fix that too but still no content is displayed

Comment: @charlietfl  $stateProvider
              .state('/home', {
               templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
               controller: 'mainController'
             })
             .state('about', {
              url: '/about',
              templateUrl: '/pages/about.html',
              controller: 'aboutController'
             })
             .state('contact', {
               url: '/contact',
               templateUrl: '/pages/contact.html',
               controller: 'contactController'
             })

Comment: @charlietfl you see the error in screenshot?

Comment: why are you testing routes in something like plunker? Never a good idea.

Comment: @Hassan that's because you magically start using a variable `scotchApp` that isn't declared. Use proper module references instead of variables. You have to use proper javascript practices as well as getting angular set up

Comment: @charlietfl could you please look this one http://plnkr.co/edit/D5S2c6rgycWFfsyfhN9J?p=preview

Comment: your paths are still wrong...now you are using absolute paths...use relative ones and plunker works fine

Comment: @charlietfl i am still stuck on empty pages can you suggest any change??

Comment: You are not looking at network of your console!!!  the clues are all there when ajax isn't working

Comment: @charlietfl i look at that but could'nt configure the problem

Comment: remove the leading `/` in templateUrl in router. Can see in network is going to wrong path

Comment: @charlietfl i now i can't move on home.html page i can only move b/w about and contact when i refresh no content is displayed on home page and now about and contact page loaded the content but i have custom directive only in home.html i guess that creating issue now

Comment: @charlietfl the main problem is there that custom directive not working

Comment: that wasn't the main problem.... you had about 5 other problems before you could even get to that one

Comment: @charlietfl yup you are right but my idea is to get custom directive working using routing that is not i getting

Comment: get directive working by itself first...you have typos in directive. I'm afraid have spent just far too much time stepping through each stage here. You need to be far more careful about labeling things

Comment: @charlietfl thankyou so much for you time http://plnkr.co/edit/D5S2c6rgycWFfsyfhN9J?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Controller is missing**
sorry i just edited it

**Edited**

1)  declare the var `var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp',['ui.router'])`

2)  in homeDirective the variable name does not match

```
    var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp');
    scotchapp.directive('homeData', function() {
```

please see the screenshot
[image]

Comment: directive doesn't have to have a controller. Can inherit from parent if that is what OP intends as it is now. This does not explain problem OP is having

Comment: @maddygoround i still got same error Uncaught ReferenceError: scotchApp is not defined(anonymous function) @ script.js:28
homeDirective.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: scotchapp is not defined(anonymous function) @ homeDirective.js:2
angular.js:9503 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: @maddygoround still nothing is displayed

Comment: @Hassan i am able to see navigation menu ,do you still see any errors ?

Comment: @maddygoround in content nothing is displayed still same error as i mention you earlier could you please look at plunker

Comment: @Hassan please see the screen shot

Comment: @Hassan stop just looking at the content and do some debugging in console

Comment: @maddygoround on my side its different

Comment: @Hassan did you made the changes i suggested ?

Comment: @maddygoround look at my screenshot i just added

Comment: var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp',['ui.router']) ,this change is still pending

Comment: in script.js file change your first line from angular.module('scotchApp',['ui.router']) to var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp',['ui.router'])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87908/discussion-between-maddygoround-and-hassan).

Answer (score 0):

**var yourapp** = angular.module('yourapp',['ui.router'])

Adding the Var yourapp = fixed my issue seems to work on everything just fine without it until I started adding directives

Comment: Please answer specifically to the question. Thanks